# Docker image pull fails with not found: manifest

Tags: docker, docker-compose, sonatype, nexus3, docker-pull

I'm using `Docker version 20.10.8, build 3967b7d` on `CentOS-7.9` host and `Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager version - OSS 3.30.1-01` being used as private docker registry. When i tried to pull the image using `docker-compose` it always fails with below error.

```
$ docker-compose up -d
Pulling prometheus (internal-registry.com:8335/prometheus:latest)...
ERROR: manifest for internal-registry.com:8335/prometheus:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
```

Error from `Sonatype Nexus server log` as follows.

```
2021-10-11 10:35:41,307+0530 WARN  [qtp657241891-125]  admin org.sonatype.nexus.repository.docker.internal.V2Handlers - Error: HEAD /v2/library/prometheus/manifests/latest: 401 - org.sonatype.nexus.repository.docker.internal.V2Exception: authentication required
2021-10-11 10:35:42,106+0530 WARN  [qtp657241891-560]  admin org.sonatype.nexus.repository.docker.internal.V2Handlers - Error: GET /v2/library/prometheus/manifests/latest: 401 - org.sonatype.nexus.repository.docker.internal.V2Exception: authentication required.
```

Docker host `docker login to our private registry` is successful.

```
1) Repo - Allow clients to use the V1 API to interact with this repository (Tick mark enabled).
2) DockerHub(Proxy) - Allow clients to use the V1 API to interact with this repository (Tick mark enabled).
3) Group - Allow clients to use the V1 API to interact with this repository (Tick mark enabled).

4) Nexus UI > Security > Anonymous Access > Allow anonymous users to access the server - (Tick mark enabled).
Username: anonymous
Realm: Local Autherizing Realm

5) Nexus UI > Security > Role > Create role > Create Nexus role > Created new role
Privileges: nx-repository-view-*-*-*-broswe
            nx-repository-view-*-*-*-read
Roles: Contained - nx-anonymous

6) Nexus UI > Security > Users > anonymous(Active)
         Roles: Granted: read_and-browse

7) Nexus UI > Security > Realms - Docker Bearer Token Realm (Is in Active List)
```

Still getting `not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown` error while pulling docker image. How do i solve this problem? Any pointer would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Did you allow anonymous read/browse on the registry on Nexus side?

Comment: @Zeitounator, Yes even `Allow anonymous docker pull ( Docker Bearer Token Realm required )` - Tick mark enabled.

Comment: Just in case: you talk about a group and a private registry. If you pull through the group, the anonymous access must be configured on the group.

Comment: `Allow anonymous docker pull` even enabled for group as well. In-fact i have upgraded my Nexus to `OSS 3.34.1-01` (Latest version). However result is same.

Comment: `Allow anonymous docker pull` and `allow anonymous read/browse on repository` are two different configurations.

Comment: `Allow anonymous read/browse on repository` option i don't have.

Comment: https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/system-configuration/access-control

Comment: Zeitounator, Thank you so much for your support.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Make sure the docker image (Above was wrong).
2. This [Link](https://www.crestdatasys.com/blogs/how-to-use-nexus-oss-user-access-management/) has helped to create a `Read` & `Browse` privilege on Repository in the Nuxus side. Post that able to pull the image successfully.

Comment: Can you please explain exact steps you did that solved the problem?

Comment: @Sniper, Please check the answer section. I have updated with details. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like some kind of network/memory/hardware issue, probably on internal-registry.com, assuming that prometheus is an available image on that registry. I would first load test that service, then verify dns, then the firewall, then the memory, then the power supply, then the hardware of that service to troubleshoot it.

Finally, I would try to recreate this error in another environment, again, against internal-registry.com. If you can't, then the issue is with the docker client, but I suspect that you will be able to replicate this issue on other clients.